# Traceback error while running python script

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to run this script

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.showmeboone.com/sheriff/JailResidents/JailResidents.asp'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.find('tbody', attrs={'class': 'stripe'})
for row in table.findAll('tr'):
print (row.prettify())
```

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
File: "C:\Users\s\Appdata\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 141, in _new_conn
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your piece of code. Look at the complete traceback. It says timeout error. The url used by you is not responding.

Also change

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

to

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: If you use soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser'), and use any working url, the code is working fine.